# What's the difference between arguments with default values and keyword-arguments?

Tags: python, syntax

In Python, what's the difference between arguments having default values:

```
def f(a,b,c=1,d=2): pass
```

and keyword arguments:

```
def f(a=1,b=2,c=3): pass
```

? I guess there's no difference, but the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) has two sections:

> 4.7.1. Default Argument Values
>
> 4.7.2. Keyword Arguments

which sounds like there are some difference in them. If so, why can't I use this syntax in 2.6:

```
def pyobj_path(*objs, as_list=False): pass
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Keyword arguments are how you call a function.

```
f( a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 )
```

Default values are how a function is defined.

Comment: Or, keyword arguments are *actual* parameters and default values are *formal* parameters.

Answer (score 11):

Default arguments mean you can leave some parameters out. Instead of `f(1, 2, 3)` you can just write `f(1)` or `f(1, 2)`.

Keyword arguments mean you don't have to put them in the same order as the function definition. Instead of `f(1, 2, 3)` you can do `f(c=3, b=2, a=1)`.

Answer (score 8):

`*args` and/or `**kwargs` must always come at the *end* of the argument list in a function declaration, if they are present. Specifically:

```
def <function name>(
        [<args without defaults>,]
        [<args with defaults>,]
        [*<variable length positional argument list name>,]
        [**<arbitrary keyward argument dict name>]
    ):
    <function body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Default values for parameters are set when defining the function with *def*. It makes passing those arguments optional when calling the function

**Define function with default value for last parameter:**

```
def name_of_function(parameter0, parameter1, default_parameter1 = 'value')
```

Parameters with default values should only be placed after simple parameters.

**Call above function (Note: argument values for parameters with default values is optional):**

```
name_of_function(parameter0, parameter1)
```

**Same function called with keyword arguments:**

```
name_of_function(parameter1='value1', parameter0='value0')
```

Keyword arguments are simple arguments. When calling a function, you could supply name-value pairs of parameter_name=value instead of just the value. This allows you to supply the arguments in a function call in any order.